# Ivanka Trump Conversion to Judaism

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

An Israel supreme rabbinical court rejected a conversion by a prominent American rabbi who sponsored Ivanka Trump’s conversion to Judaism, reaffirming a widely criticized ruling by a lower court.

Why did the court hold that the rabbi's conversion of Ivanka Trump to Judaism was invalid?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying which additional info you are looking for

Comment: This is a question about an individual.  Quite aside from the fact that such questions are off-topic, do you really think it's proper to talk about another person like this?

Answer (score 4):

As you state:

> An Israel supreme rabbinical court rejected a conversion by a prominent American rabbi who sponsored Ivanka Trump’s conversion to Judaism.

That is, they are supposed to have *rejected* **a** particular conversion by the rabbi; not all of his conversions, and not his conversion of Ivanka Trump. In actuality they did not reject the conversion, but they requested details of that conversion (which predated the current central bais din system) and the final result was that that conversion was certified.

In the [words of](http://www.cross-currents.com/archives/2016/07/11/thoughts-on-the-conversion-mess/) R. Yitzchak Adlerstein:

> The recent matter regarding a long-ago conversion conducted by Rav
>   Haskel Lookstein, for which the Israeli Chief Rabbinate requested more
>   documentation, generated great media attention because, years later,
>   he also was associated with the halakhic conversion of Ivanka
>   Trump....As facts actually have it, Ms. Trump was converted under the
>   GPS rubric. There is no question regarding her conversion. She was
>   converted with the full institutional imprimatur. By contrast, Rav
>   Lookstein’s earlier conversions that pre-dated the GPS...

So again, there was no question regarding her conversion which was conducted following set guidelines. The issue regarded earlier conversions of R. Lookstein, which were done before the GPS (Geirus Policies and Standards Network) was set up. The GPS is an agreement between the Rabbinical Council of America and the Israeli Chief Rabbinate, see [here](http://www.judaismconversion.org/).